# MVC return view and navigate to page within that view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller, navigation, return

Using C# MVC. I need to return the view if the user enters invalid information into the form.
Code is:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return View();
   }
```

But the Home view contains several pages within it that can be navigated to (#about, #services, #gallery, #contact). So once the page reloads it goes directly to the Home page (when I click Contact it navigates there and I can see the error messages) but I need it to navigate to the Contact page automatically so the user can see their error message and how to fix it.

I have tried

```
string url = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath+ "#contact";
return redirect(url);
```

This redirects the page to #contact BUT does not show the error message.

Any other suggestions, kindly assist

Comment: Which error do you expect to see?

Comment: @lnanikian If the user enters invalid data into the form, the form will return "your email address is incorrect, please change it" for example. Thats what I mean by the error message

Comment: Could you show your model please? The code of the view also?

Comment: See the post I made here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41682322/how-to-return-to-a-named-anchor-in-page-when-modelstate-is-not-valid/41686203#41686203